# Does Bazel work with Grails?

Tags: grails, bazel

[Bazel](https://bazel.build/) is a multi-language build tool from Google that acts as a replacement for things like Maven, Gradle, Make, etc. There are articles written on [how to migrate from Gradle to Bazel](https://www.pgrs.net/2015/09/01/migrating-from-gradle-to-bazel/), for instance. But I wonder if this tool works with Grails.

[Grails](https://grails.org/) is a web app framework that uses Gradle, but from what I've seen it's a bit more than that. For lack of a better term, Grails itself acts as a "wrapper" for common tasks such as building an app as a WAR or JAR file, running the app locally with different profiles, or scaffolding new files and features. Popular IDEs such as IntelliJ have Grails plugins available to run these Grails commands. So it seems to me like it's perhaps tightly coupled to the Gradle build script that backs it.

It also seems to me that just because Bazel says it supports Gradle projects doesn't necessarily imply that it supports Grails projects, because of all these reasons regarding Grails being more than just Gradle. But I wanted to ask the community if my assumptions are true, or if, in fact, people are already using Bazel as a substitute for Gradle inside Grails projects. Can it be done?

Comment: "Everything" Grails3 brings, can be also used from Gradle, as in: there are Gradle tasks for many things (e.g. `dbmGormDiff`).  E.g. I always use the "Gradle" ways in Grails project and never what the Grails-CLI-Tool brings. So my guess is, that it should work.

Comment: why would someone want to switch from battle-proven gradle to something strange?

Answer (score 0):

Bazel could in theory be used to build grails projects as it is fundamentally agnostic to the type of thing being built.  That said, grails probably works well with gradle out of the box and you'd have to re-implement a number of things yourself again and probably is not worth the effort.  If you are a large shop and have multiple other languages that you need to support however, it may be worth investing in the effort.

https://github.com/pubref/rules_maven supports using a gradle file to determine transitive maven dependencies if you want to investigate further.